# Python Not Loading Server Certificate

Tags: python-3.x, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send an http post request to an external server. Here is my code

```
path = DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH
r = post(
    url,
    data=payload,
    headers=headers,
    pkcs12_filename="pfxcert.pfx",
    pkcs12_password="password",
    verify=path,
)
```

I opened the cacert.pem file from the DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH location and opened my server certificate in a notepad and copied the content at the end of the DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH file. When I run this code, I still get error

> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))

[image]